# how to find activeelement in chrome in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to find activeelement in chrome how to do this ,In IE 
i have written code as

`document.activeElement.id`

but what is the replacment for this code in chrome

Comment: Did you mean the element with focus?

Comment: Your question is not clear - what exactly are you trying to do? Get the `id` attribute of that element?

Comment: As stated on the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.activeElement), this code is supported by all major browsers...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this jquery code:

```
$(':focus')
```